# Does there exist a surjective but not injective homomorphism of rings from an integral domain R → R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, ring-homomorphism

I could come up with examples for rings;say for example defining the homomorphism to be a left shift of elements which are taken to be of the form of a countably infinite tuple.Can someone help me out by giving an example for Integral Domains

Comment: Trivially, take a polynomial ring over a field in infinitely many variables.

Comment: ... and take the quotient by one of those variables and notice what the quotient looks like.